# Google Maps showing wrong Longitude value using PHP, MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Marker, which shows multiple locations. The code is working fine but it is automatically adding multiple numbers to `long` value.

For example:

The XML file have the following value of long and lat:

```
Lat:28.4263
Long:77.0477
```

Map is fetching the above data from my database.

This is my `index.php`, which contains the map code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var customLabel = {
    flat: {
      label: 'F'
    },
    bar: {
      label: 'B'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.593788, 78.962988,false),
      zoom: 5
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
      downloadUrl('map_back.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
            geocoder.geocode({
          address: markerElem.getAttribute('address')
        }, function(geocoderResults) {
          let latlng = geocoderResults[0].geometry.location; // a LatLng object
          console.log(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
        });
          var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var lats=parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat'));
          var longs=parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('long'));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lats,longs,false);
          alert(point);
          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label

          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });

        });

      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

On this page, when I alert my long and lat values, they show up like this:

```
28.4263, 77.04770000000000054
```

I have tried to fix the decimal values using `.toFixed()`, but still it showing multiple numbers after the values. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between `77.0477` and `77.04770000000000054`?

Comment: i have 77.0477 in my dataabase.. at var point=new google.maps.LatLng..... it changes to 77.0477000000000054 and map does not show the correct location @geocodezip

Comment: That difference is not going to be visible.  If the "map does not show the correct location", something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Searching:
This is a floating point rounding error introduced by google's longitude wrapping function.

If you're absolutely sure that your latitude is between -90 and 90, and longitude between -180 and 180, you could pass true to the noWrap parameter of the LatLng constructor and the wrapping function will be bypassed.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

Be wary, though - if your coordinates are outside of these bounds, some API features will break.

Comment: should i do like this var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lats,longs,false); ?

Comment: Yes, it appears so.

Comment: It is not an error.  Floating point numbers don't represent numbers exactly.

Comment: @TimDavis I have updated the code but still have the same issue

Comment: @geocodezip the issue is with this line `new google.maps.LatLng` coz the value changes here. if i alert values of lat and long before this line they are correct. but when i print after `new google.maps.LatLng` it changes.

Comment: @denny Sorry I dont have another suggestions but it doesn't really appear to be a problem.. The difference between those two numbers is literally 10 billionth of a point off, and that's how floating point works. Perhaps you should research why your location is wrong as that would only be off by like 10millimeters

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var html = [];

var getprice = [];

<?php
 

foreach($rent as $key => $val)

{
 
?>
 

   
  getprice[<?php echo $rent[$key];?>] = '<?php echo $rent[$key];?>';
  
  
  html[<?php echo $key;?>] = '<div class="col-sm-12">
  
  <div style="float:left">'+getprice[<?php echo $rent[$key];?>]+'</div>';
  
<?php

}

?>


 var locations = [<?php echo $latlngstring; ?>
 
  ];

function myMap() {

  var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $first;?>);
  
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map1");
  
  var mapOptions = {center: myCenter, zoom: 14};
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  
  setMarkers(map,locations)
  
function setMarkers(map,locations){


      var marker, i

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)

 {  

 
 var lat = locations[i][0]
 
 var long = locations[i][1]
 

 latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 
var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png");

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
  
          map: map,  position: latlngset,
          icon: pinImage  
        });
        
var content =  html[i]    

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 

        return function() {
        
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
            
        };
        
    })(marker,content,infowindow));
    
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout',

(function(marker, content, infowindow) {

      return function() {
      
        infowindow.close();
        
      };
      
    })(marker, content, infowindow));



  }
  
  }

}

console.error();

</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourapi=myMap"></script>
```

```html
I am using Google Maps Marker, which shows multiple locations with price show  from database value long , lat based using php , mysql 


<div id="map1" style="color: #24e2c6;min-height: 250px; width: 100% !important;"> 
            
          
                
</div>

<?php 

$lat = array();

$long = array();

//$rent = array();

$queryString = "SELECT postroom.latitude AS latitude,postroom.longitude AS longitude FROM `postroom`
WHERE  addcustomer.id=postroom.user_id";

                  
$sql_latlong = mysqli_query($con,$queryString) or

die(mysqli_error($con));

$latlngstring = '';

$first = '';

$i=0;
  
  $image= array();
  
while($row_latlong = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_latlong)){

 
 if($first == '')
  
 {
  
$first =  $row_latlong['latitude'].",".$row_latlong['longitude'];

 }
  
 $latlngstring .= "[".$row_latlong['latitude'].",".$row_latlong['longitude']."],";
  



 
$rent[] =  $row_latlong['Rent'];  
    
}

$latlngstring = substr($latlngstring,0,-1);


?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? Why do you think that it solves the problem? Which parts where neccessary? Please do not only post code, this makes it nearly impossible for the OP to spot his error